# Error in very simple C++ program

Tags: c++

So I made this simple program from tutorial, and I get an error that says

> Intellisense expected a ';'

The error is on this line `int main()`  line 19

This is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class WilboClass{
public:
        void setName(string x) {
                name = x;
        }
        string getName() {
                return name;
        }
private:
        string name;
}

int main()
{
        WilboClass wo;
        wo.setName("Sir Wilbo Wallace");
        cout << wo.getName();

        Sleep(5000);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think that after class CLASS {}; definition should be ';'

Comment: **Stop vandalizing this post.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to add semicolon `;` after class definition.

```
class WilboClass{
  public:
    void setName(string x) {
            name = x;
    }
    string getName() {
            return name;
    }
 private:
    string name;
};  // <--  add here
```

Comment: @Wilbo007, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider 
[accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some
reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The class definition should be terminated with a `;`.